# can I read the numeric position of a vector<string>::iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a vector of string.  I want to be able to search that vector for a string and if I get a match in the vector, I'd like to be able to return the position e.g. the vector index of the item in the vector.

Here's the code I'm trying to solve the problem for:

```
enum ActorType  { at_none, at_plane, at_sphere, at_cylinder, at_cube, at_skybox, at_obj, at_numtypes };

class ActorTypes
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string>  _sActorTypes;

public:
    ActorTypes()
    {
        // initializer lists don't work in vs2012 :/
        using std::string;
        _sActorTypes.push_back( string("plane") );
        _sActorTypes.push_back( string("sphere") );
        _sActorTypes.push_back( string("cylinder") );
        _sActorTypes.push_back( string("cube") );
        _sActorTypes.push_back( string("skybox") );
        _sActorTypes.push_back( string("obj") );
    }

    const ActorType FindType( const std::string & s )
    {
        auto itr = std::find( _sActorTypes.cbegin(), _sActorTypes.cend(), s );

        uint32_t nIndex = ???;

        // I want to be able to do the following
        return (ActorType) nIndex;
    }       
};
```

I know I can just write a for loop and return the for loop index that I find the match at, but I was wondering for the more general case - can I get the index value of a vector::iterator ??

Comment: `nIndex = itr - _sActorTypes.cbegin();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `std::distance`:

```
uint32_t index = std::distance(std::begin(_sActorTypes), itr);
```

You should check the return value of `find` to `end()` first, though, to make sure it's actually found. You could also use subtraction since `std::vector` uses a random-access iterator, but subtraction will not work for all containers, such as `std::list`, which uses a bidirectional iterator.

Comment: for some reason, vs2012 doesn't like std::begin(_sActorTypes), but does like _sActorType.begin().  No matter, your answer solves my query, thanks!

Comment: @lapin, `std::begin` is C++11. It's a force of habit for me, sorry. There's not much difference between the two.

Comment: @lapin, Maybe. I have a vague memory of not being able to use it there, now that you mention it.

Comment: @lapin : `std::begin` doesn't work here because `_sActorTypes` is non-const in this context, so you're attempting to pass `distance` both an `iterator` and a `const_iterator` (since you used `cbegin()` to initialize `itr`). VC++ 2012 is not in error here. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn, Oh, does the free version not do both const and not like `.begin()` does?

Comment: @chris : In the general case (i.e. for standard containers) `std::begin` simply returns `container.begin()`, so given a non-const container an `iterator` will be returned, and given a const container a `const_iterator` will be returned. If `ActorTypes::FindType` were `const` (as it _should_ be), your code would work as-is since `_sActorTypes` would contextually be const.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
auto itr = std::find( _sActorTypes.cbegin(), _sActorTypes.cend(), s );
uint32_t nIndex = std::distance(_sActorTypes.cbegin(), itr);
```